# Application Getting crash when send email with intent

Tags: android-intent, gmail

I want to send a email using Intent. But when I select Gmail for this action I get

> FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1 Process: com.google.android.gm,
>   PID: 9855 java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:613)
>   at com.google.android.gm.provider.aV.b(SourceFile:6237) at
>   com.google.android.gm.provider.bh.HC(SourceFile:4213) at
>   com.google.android.gm.provider.bh.(SourceFile:4186) at
>   com.google.android.gm.provider.bo.a(SourceFile:3898) at
>   com.google.android.gm.provider.Operations.b(SourceFile:628) at
>   com.google.android.gm.provider.aV.a(SourceFile:5936) at
>   com.google.android.gm.provider.MailSync.a(SourceFile:899) at
>   com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.a(SourceFile:2399) at
>   com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.a(SourceFile:2129) at
>   com.google.android.gm.provider.bp.a(SourceFile:127) at
>   com.google.android.common.b.onPerformSync(SourceFile:33) at
>   com.google.android.gm.provider.bp.onPerformSync(SourceFile:82) at
>   android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:259)

Comment: Where is your logcat then ??? and where is your code????

Comment: i am reffering from  [link](http://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-send-email-in-android-using-intent) this link

Comment: Hi welcome to the world of programming. and please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Update your post without posting logcat as a anwer

Comment: What is the intent? What version of Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

have you implemented like this

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "EXTRA_SUBJECT");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Hope this will help.